# Echo'd links showing after my web address

Tags: php, href

Just a quick question obviously has a simple solution, however I am unable to find it...

Would anyone be kind anough to point me in the right direction on why this piece of code is showing up after my directory in the new tab...

```
echo "<td><a href='$row[link_address]' target='new'>" . $row['link_address']. "</a></td>";
```

Once the new tab opens it is echo'ing the link after my web address, for example www.mysite.com/$row['link_address'] I am obviously looking for this to be just the link and not a forward slash after my directory.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give us an example of the value of `$row[link_address]`?

Comment: are you saying you dont want a forward slash after your url?

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your reply... This would simply be either http://www.abc.com or www.abc.com in the sql table.

Comment: **http colon - that appeared as a link

Comment: Hi Sergio, yes that's correct, I don't want the clicked link to appear after the directory(my url) I just want the data in the sql table as the complete url

Comment: Are you saying that they sometimes do and sometimes don't have `http://` at the start? Can you edit your question and add an example of the HTML output of the PHP code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute links (where the entire URL is in the link) need to start with the protocol part of the link (eg `http://` or `https://`).

Otherwise, the browser assumes the link is to a *directory* called `abc.com` on your domain, rather than to the `abc.com` domain.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for that if this link was taken from a previous user input would I need to specify that they need to put in the full http: path?

Comment: You could do that; you could also test to see if it's there and add it automatically if not.

Comment: Does the problem still happen when you use a link that *does* start with `http://`?

Comment: No the problem is fixed if I input the http path, so thank you for that! I will have to have a look at validation if it is not written in full form, I really should of thought my own question through more, still new to this. Thanks again for your help, much appreciated! :)

Comment: Anytime, glad I could help! (By the way, if your problem is fixed, don't forget to click the green check mark to the left of the answer to mark it as accepted.)